# Integration level for Ansible: between roles and playbooks

Tags: ansible, dependencies

I'm trying to find a solution for the following problem:
We have some playbook-level code (many roles, running on different hosts), which we would like to reuse between projects.

I can't find a way for well-thought (seamless/good/etc) way to integrate other's playbooks into mine's.

Key points of integration:

- playbook and it's role vendoring with a proper dependency management
- ability to clearly see and name things that were vendored
- ability to update vendored dependencies
- isolation of internals (I don't want to trigger some unexpected handlers and/or `set_fact` someone's variables for role shadowing their value)

Additional problem is how to handle this in git (if there is git-level integration).

Are there some best practices for such integration? Do they exist?

(Insofar I decided to use git-vendor for this, but I hope there are better ways).

Answer (score 0):

I understand the motivation behind the ideas you describe, but I am thinking the solution you have in mind might not be in line with how Ansible is designed.
I will explain my point of view, and try to address your key points along the way.

Ansible emphasizes role level abstraction. In terms of dependency management, there is the [`ansible-galaxy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/galaxy.html#the-command-line-tool) command, which is bundled with Ansible.
It can also be [pointed to custom repository URLs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/galaxy.html#version).
`ansible-galaxy install git+https://github.com/my-repo/my-ansible-role`
There are also examples in the documentation that show how to set up a requirements file, to install a set of (custom) dependencies.
This should at least fulfill your technical requirements regarding "vendoring".

That being said, you specifically mentioned "playbook-level code".
This implies that you also want to share the inventory, because playbooks are basically the mapping of hosts to roles.
(If your playbooks are much more than a list of roles, or includes of other playbooks, you might want to think about refactoring more into roles, see above.)

In terms of Ansible's design and philosophy, it de-emphasizes sharing playbooks, because they should be rather simple to begin with, and pointless without an inventory.
And the inventory is presumably shared among your organsation to begin with, i.e. there is only one "version" of it.

From my experience, Ansible works best, when everything is in one directory, i.e. inventory, installed roles, playbooks, as [their documentation suggests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#content-organization).
Keep it simple, and in terms of sharing, try to introduce the members of other projects to work with that source of information.

If this is a consideration in terms of security or team policies, consider using [Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/vault.html) or similar to share secrets.

To solve the problem of shared variables, you could consider using one of the [Cache pluins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html) to cache facts between different playbook invocations, on different machines.
In this way, your roles can refer variables that are "coming from your environment" rather than from the state of the machine running the playbook.

Last but not least, Ansible's approach to this problem is their actual commercial product [Ansible Tower](https://www.ansible.com/products/tower), a user interface and API to run Ansible playbooks, the core of which is an open source project called [AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx).

Comment: The key point of integration between roles is not only 'hosts/plays' level, but shared variables. If I configure foo on server foo-server and bar on bar-server I want them both to use the same settings for foobar. Roles do not allow this. Moreover, industry is heavy on playbooks: ceph-ansible, kubespray, openshift - all them provides playbooks, as it's impossible to implement with roles only.

Comment: Added another paragraph regarding fact caching.
I would say that the case of "industry playbooks" could be interpreted as "Ansible projects" being shared, i.e. a single repository, where everything (roles, inventory, playbooks) is located inside, basically what I am referring to in my answer.